# Iam trying to copy image from a url but gets an error for connection refused

Tags: php, instagram

I have developed an application in which Iam fetching images from instagram and displaying them in popup and then trying to downlaod an image on click of image but always getting error for connection refused.The same code works well for facebook images but not with the instagram images.
The error is :-
failed to open stream: Connection refused 
I have tried several methods for saving image like `copy` , `fput`, `curl`,`file_get_content` .But no progress.
When i tried same code on other servers it works,but not on http://viewyourdev.com

I am attaching link to my test application:
http://viewyourdev.com/testinstagram.

Please help.

Comment: You will have to attach the code in question; just post the part which is trying to get the image from a URL.

Comment: I have mentioned the php functions that i have tried for my code.

Comment: The correct function is `file_get_contents` - with an "s" at the end. Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283995/file-get-contents-connection-refused-for-my-own-site) discussion as it might provide you with some answers.

Comment: I have tried the code given in the link ,it works for creating an image of 840 kb.When it is opened it is blank image created.Here is my code,please tell me where iam going wrong.

Comment: `$img= $_REQUEST['fburl'];
$path = pathinfo($img);
$image = $path['basename'];
$ch= curl_init($img);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://test.com/abc');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: test.com')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,'');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$fp = fopen('file-upload/'.$image,'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE,$fp);
curl_exec($ch);
fclose($fp);
curl_close($ch);'

Comment: See PHP/Apache error logs and post them here. If an error occurred during the download, you should see it there. Also, edit your original question and add the code there instead, it will be more readable.