# file_get_contents failed to open stream: Connection refused godaddy server with remote connection server

Tags: sql-server, remote-server, php

Our url is remote url.i can run through Ip address.it thrown error as "file_get_contents failed to open stream: Connection refused".I have use this code.

code:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx/apps/index.php');
print_r($html);
var_dump($html);
```

What does this error?

Comment: it working in local and any pc but it not working on godaddy server

Comment: possible duplicate of [file\_get\_contents() connection refused for my own site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283995/file-get-contents-connection-refused-for-my-own-site)

Comment: @Lorenz Meyer, m not getting that point.

Comment: but i have connect to remote server url then error display for file_get_contents failed to open stream: Connection refused

Answer (score 2):

A lot of hosts will prevent you from loading files from remote URLs for security reasons (allow_url_fopen setting in php.ini). It's better to use CURL to download the contents of the file.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx/apps/index.php';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Ref: [Get file content via PHP cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781876/get-file-content-via-php-curl)

HTH :)

Comment: When i used this code it returns blank page. It does not displayed any error.

Answer (score 1):

Getting a page would require you to open a stream.
Something like this:

```
<?php
// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/', false, $context);
?>
```

For reference please check PHP.net: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: file_get_contents(): failed to open stream: No such file or directory error fire