# how to properly load json in php?

Tags: php, json

I've tried other SO pages but can't find a solution.

I have a json file that i'm trying to import into a php file but it returns NULL.

The json on my web server is valid and yet no luck.

```
http://higconsolidated.com/json.json
```

PHP file:

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://higconsolidated.com/json.json');
$obj = json_decode($json);
var_dump($obj);
```

Error log:

> file_get_contents(higconsolidated.com/json.json): failed to open
>   stream: Connection refused in getjson.php

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can i see your JSON?

Comment: It's working fine at my end though. I am getting response "d", is that true?

Comment: aldrin27  check it out http://higconsolidated.com/json.json

Comment: disha  "d" should not be it..

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? There's nothing wrong with your code

Comment: json.json): failed to open stream: Connection refused in par.php

Comment: This isn't a problem with your code, most likely your machine's firewall or such. Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283995/file-get-contents-connection-refused-for-my-own-site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PHP you are using `json.json` instead of `json.php`. Probably `json.json` doesn't exist.

*After your update*:
For me, having a file

```
<?php
  $json = file_get_contents('http://higconsolidated.com/json.json');
  $obj = json_decode($json);
  var_dump($obj);
?>
```

yields `array(47) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1 (5) { ["code"]=> string(4) "1031" ["par"]=> string(1) "1" ["category"]=> string(1) "A" ["product"]=> string(18) "FIDJI QUINOA SALAD" ["format"]=> string(5) "2x1kg" } [1]=>...`

In case you have additional code, please try using the above minimal file.

*After second update*: Your problem has nothing to do with parsing JSON. It seems you run into some kind of request / traffic limit or firewall issue. Is `higconsolidated.com` the same host you are running your PHP file on?

Comment: i see this in my error logs. even with your bare minimum code.. file get contents Connection refused

Comment: file_get_contents(http://higconsolidated.com/json.json): failed to open stream: Connection refused in getjson.php

Comment: Works now..  only i had to use the local file as a work around.. for now

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://higconsolidated.com/json.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is right, but let me suggest you to check the format of the json file you are using.

```
<?php

// the following strings are valid JavaScript but not valid JSON

// the name and value must be enclosed in double quotes
// single quotes are not valid 
$bad_json = "{ 'bar' : 'baz' }";
json_decode($bad_json); // null

// the name must be enclosed in double quotes
$bad_json = '{ "bar" : "baz" }';
json_decode($bad_json); // null

// trailing commas are not allowed
$bad_json = '{ "bar" : "baz", }';
json_decode($bad_json); // null

?>
```

Take a look at here http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://higconsolidated.com/json.json');
$obj = json_decode($json);
foreach ($obj as $value) 
{
    //you can retrieve all the keys here
    echo $value->code."<br>" ;
}
```